# Can't stretch a control in a stackpanel

Tags: silverlight, stretch

Here is a piece of my control code:

```
    <telerik:RadWindow>
    <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue">
            <Grid
    x:Name="DetailsGrid">
                <prismvm:DataTemplateSelector
        Content="{Binding NewTemplate}">
                    <prismvm:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
                        <DataTemplate
                x:Key="EmailMessageTemplate">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red">
                                <TextBlock Text="Name: "/>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Green"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Subject: "/>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding EmailSubject,Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Body: "/>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Body,Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>

                            </StackPanel>

                            </DataTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate
                    x:Key="SmsMessageTemplate">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Subject: "/>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Sms body: "/>

                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Body,Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                                </StackPanel>

                            </DataTemplate>

                        </prismvm:DataTemplateSelector.Resources>
                    </prismvm:DataTemplateSelector>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
    </telerik:RadWindow>
```

The problem is that at start the width of the textboxes is very little and I need to have width the same as grid.

How can I do it?

**EDIT**
I've updated my xaml, and now every element looks like at the picture:

[image]

Comment: I notice you only have `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on one template. Was that intentional?

Comment: Without your complete code I can only mock up parts of it. I do not get the same result however. I will continue to investigate...

Comment: I don't know, but maybe this d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
     ResizeMode="NoResize" Width="355" has connection with my problem. Sorry, but I couldn't expose my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added

`HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

to

```
<prismvm:DataTemplateSelector
        Content="{Binding NewTemplate}">
```

and now it works fine.

Comment: Or <Style TargetType="prismvm:DataTemplateSelector" ><Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" /></Style> in generic.xaml.

Answer (score 0):

A StackPanel does not stretch to fit its parent container by default (in this case column 0 of the Grid, or rather the entire grid).

Try this on the outer StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Then the child TextBoxes have something to stretch to.

*When in doubt, set different background colours on your various containers so you can see how much room they take up at runtime.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Now I have a result as as attached printscreen

Comment: I think it may be your Grid inside the StackPanel that's not stretching, can you put a background color on that too?

Comment: @BillReiss I've check it, and Grid with x:Name="DetailsGrid" fills entire stackpanel, but thanks gor your reply.